# Degree of boolean functions

Tags: boolean-algebra

How can we compute the degree of boolean function? I encountered with this,while solving a problem given in my assignment module which is,

> How many different boolean functions
>   of degree 1 and 2 are there?

The suggest answer in my module is $4$ and $16$,but I don't understand how and what exactly meant by the degree of boolean functions,could somebody explain?

**EDIT:** I encountered [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BooleanFunction.html) today,but I don't understand is it $2^{2^p}$ or $2^{2p}$ ?

Comment: In your book how is the degree of a function defined? Even better give some more info about the context.

Comment: @Arjang:The degree is not defined,that is the problem.

Comment: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847188/degree-of-boolean-functions) link.

Comment: I think it is 2^(2^p). On the page you linked to, they found the truth table for the $2^{2^2}$ possible boolean functions of two variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that *degree* refers to the arity of the function, the number of input variables. (But you should check the definition, and the question is not really mathematically sensible without a precise definition.) Since the number of rows of a truth table with $p$ Boolean variables is $2^p$, and each row can get one of two values (true or false), the number of such truth tables is $2^{2^p}$. This is $2$ to the number of rows, since there are two possibilities for each of the $2^p$ rows.

Every such truth table determines a Boolean function in $p$ variables, and every Boolean function in $p$ variables is determined by its corresponding truth table. Thus, the total number of Boolean functions in $p$-variables is $2^{2^p}$. 
(And this is not the same as $2^{2p}$.)

Thus, when $p$ is $1$, we have $2^{2^1}=4$ Boolean unary functions, and when $p$ is $2$, we have $2^{2^2}=16$ Boolean binary functions.

Comment: To me, and this is standard terminology in theoretical CS, the degree of a boolean function would mean the degree of its polynomial (Fourier) representation. But it seems unlikely that the term is used in this sense here; also I do not see a nice way to count these.

Comment: Ah, that would be yet another meaning for *degree*, and I think we are all agreed that the question is only sensible when the intended meaning of this term has been made clear.

Comment: @Srivatsan could you please elaborate a bit further on the polynomial Fourier representation of a Boolean function?